# ContentDialog Windows 10 Mobile XAML - FullScreen - Padding

Tags: c#, xaml, authentication, popup, windows-10-mobile

I put an ContentDialog in my project to use for Login Popup on Windows 10.
When I run this project on mobile, ContentDialog not shown in full screen and have a minimal padding around this element.On keyboard is visible (on focus element textbox for example) exist margin between keyboard and content dialog

Have any solution to how this on FullScreen? I set the property "FullSizeDesired" true, mas the problem is the same?

Someone help to remove this: - Padding, - Full Screen

My code are:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="ExampleApp.SignInContentDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ExampleApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="SIGN IN">

    <Grid x:Name="GridMobile" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

            <Button x:Name="MakeOff" 
            Height="32" BorderThickness="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="Red" Background="Black"
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
            Margin="0">

            <HyperlinkButton x:Name="btnRegister"
            Height="32" BorderThickness="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="Red" Background="Black"
            Margin="0"
            NavigateUri="www.google.pt"
            Style="{StaticResource HyperLinkButtonStyleMobile}"
            Content="Register">
                <HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
            </HyperlinkButton>
    </Grid>
```

The margin/space have in button of page is reserved for the "PrimaryButton" and "SecondaryButton" I think
 but I need more buttons and this margin/space is not appropriated for me. I want to remove this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your custom `ContentDialog` xaml?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not allowed post images here.
 Can you give your skypei id or another to communicate with you about this?

I edit this post right now!

Thanks

Comment: Well, why can't you post your code here?

Comment: I post now! Please chek this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that you see the gaps in between is not because of any specific `Padding` values but because in `ContentDialog`'s default style, the height and width are set to `Auto` which means your content will only be given the size it needs to.

So make the content stretch to fit its parent, you just need to override the default style by applying your own default style of the `local:SignInContentDialog` and put it inside your `App.xaml`.

```
<Style TargetType="local:SignInContentDialog">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMaxHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMaxWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:SignInContentDialog">
                <Border x:Name="Container">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">                                                     
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!-- COMMENT OUT THESE FOLLOWING LINES -->

                        <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}">
                            <Grid x:Name="DialogSpace" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ZoomMode="Disabled" Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentScrollViewerMargin}" IsTabStop="False">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <ContentControl x:Name="Title" Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMargin}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsTabStop="False" MaxHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMaxHeight}">
                                            <ContentControl.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" MaxLines="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </ContentControl.Template>
                                        </ContentControl>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontSize="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentMargin}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                                <Grid x:Name="CommandSpace" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Border x:Name="Button1Host" Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButton1HostMargin}" MinWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMinWidth}" MaxWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMaxWidth}" Height="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                    <Border x:Name="Button2Host" Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButton2HostMargin}" MinWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMinWidth}" MaxWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMaxWidth}" Height="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonHeight}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Ok, but, I copy this style for App.xaml.
The Visual Studio show error "Unknow target type 'local:SignInContentDialog'".
Help me in this problem.

Comment: You need to define the namespace on the top - `xmlns:local="using:YourNamespaceName"`.

Comment: Type "xmlns:local="using: SignInContentDialog"?

Comment: No... `xmlns:local="using:ExampleApp`.

Comment: Oh, I try but the studio show me errors :(
My App name is: "Windows10Programming"
My View have ContentDialog name is: MyDialogSignIn
This my view is in directory: Windows10Programming.Client.Views.MyDialogSignIn

Comment: `local:SignInContentDialog` --> `local:MyDialogSignIn`;  `xmlns:local="using:ExampleApp` --> `xmlns:local="using:Windows10Programming.Client.Views`.

Comment: Thanks. Work but on focus textbox for example, the contentDialog slides down and create a small margin on top and buttons looked (where the de Primary and Secondary buttons are, not have buttons but have the space for them.)crop when keyboard appear but i have space necessary to show all elements in display of Lumia. In this case is really necessary to do scroll down.

This style override all, but I need this override only in mobile version. In desktop version my content dialog works fine! I try open dialog on Desktop mode and dialog not appear :(

Comment: This is a system behavior and there's no easy way to fix I'm afraid. But you can try whenever your TextBox gets focused (GotFocus), give the whole dialog a negative top margin by doing - this.Margin = new Thickness(0,-12,0,0); and set it back to 0 when LostFocus is called.

Comment: And for this problem, have any trick to fix? " This style override all, but I need this override only in mobile version. In desktop version my content dialog works fine! I try open dialog on Desktop mode and dialog not appear :("
I Work on UniversalApp - Windows 10, but I have different code for the different devices Mobile vs Desktop

Comment: Give the style a name. When you instantiate the dialog, check if it's mobile, if it is, then assign the style.

Comment: Ok, Work. The space alocated for Primary and Secondary Button. It's possible to remove?
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: On focus any element, type TextBox, the keyboard appear.
When Keyboard appear, have a big margin above( so 20-30 px maybe). This space is the same height of the space allocated for Primary and Secondary Buttons. 
If have this margin, my content have a scrollbar and I do not want it. I have space sufficient to show all content of my dialog if remove this margin/padding of course. Understand?

Comment: Put this in a different question. This is not related to this one.

Comment: Ok. I open new questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615093/remove-margin-button-contentdialog-windows-10-mobile-xaml