# Remove Margin Button ContentDialog Windows 10 Mobile - XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, dialog, margins, windows-10-mobile

In my ContentDialog. On focus any element, type TextBox, the keyboard appear. When Keyboard appear, have a big margin above( so 20-30 px maybe). This space is the same height of the space allocated for Primary and Secondary Buttons. If have this margin, my content have a scrollbar and I do not want it. I have space sufficient to show all content of my dialog if remove this margin/padding of course.

This topic is related with: [ContentDialog Windows 10 Mobile XAML - FullScreen - Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605138/contentdialog-windows-10-mobile-xaml-fullscreen-padding/32612930?noredirect=1#comment53080680_32612930)

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">


             <TextBox x:Name="txtUser" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
             Background="Black" Foreground="Red  BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"
             PlaceholderText="Digit your username"
             GotFocus="txtUser_GotFocus" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" 
             TextChanged="txtUser_TextChanged"
             />

            <Button x:Name="MakeOff" 
            Height="32" BorderThickness="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="Red" Background="Black"
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
            Margin="0">

            <HyperlinkButton
            Height="32" BorderThickness="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="Red" Background="Black"
            Margin="0"
            NavigateUri="www.google.pt"
            Style="{StaticResource HyperLinkButtonStyleMobile}"
            Content="Register">
                <HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
            </HyperlinkButton>

            <Button 
            Height="32" BorderThickness="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="Red" Background="Black"
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
            Margin="0">

            <HyperlinkButton x:Name="btnRegisterTwo"
            Height="32" BorderThickness="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="Red" Background="Black"
            Margin="0"
            NavigateUri="www.google.pt"
            Style="{StaticResource HyperLinkButtonStyleMobile}"
            Content="Register">
                <HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
            </HyperlinkButton>

          <Button x:Name="MakeOffThree" 
            Height="32" BorderThickness="1" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="Red" Background="Black"
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
            Margin="0">
          </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
```

Someone help to remove this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you also add the code for the textboxes and buttons?

Comment: Justin XL, Check it!

Comment: Where is the textbox?

Comment: I don't see any scrollbars... Can you paste your full xaml code?

Comment: Scroll bar is native for ContentDialog. If not have space to show full content, scroll bar is active. See on override style, available on link above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89842/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-fipcurren88).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the `ContentScrollViewer` inside the style is given a fixed height during run-time, and a hack is to remove this `x:Name` from the `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ZoomMode="Disabled" Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentScrollViewerMargin}" IsTabStop="False">
```

Also, you will need to add the `RowDefinitions` back to the root panel `LayoutRoot` in the style.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Great. Work.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have only a problem. When landscape mode is activated, the popup disappear. Before, mobile stayed portrait mode.(In my lumia)

Comment: Dialog disappear or only appear part of dialog.

Comment: It works fine on my emulator. Did you set the *Supported rotations:* inside *Package.appxmainfest*?

Comment: Only Portrait-Flipped is uncheked